# Restartin Powershell and Continue

Tags: powershell

I am creating a ps script that automates the setup of the development environment. I am using chocolatey (chocolatey.org) to install node and ruby and then try to install number of node packages and gems. This is where things start to go wrong. Both ruby and node require powershell to restart to be detected.

So does anyone know a work around that either refreshes powershell, or some other way around this limitation?

Here is a stripped down version of the script to reproduce the issue :

```
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))    
cinst ruby
gem install compass --pre
```

which gives an error

```
gem : The term 'gem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Or similarly with node

```
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))    
cinst nodejs.install
cinst npm
npm install -g bower
```

which gives an error

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Which version of chocolatey are you using? What packages/gems are you installing? What errors are you getting? The latest version of chocolatey updates the current environment so you run newly installed commands immediately, so you'll need to give more details on what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @mike-z I am downloading chocolatey from the site in the script, so I assumed it was the latest. I have given some script snippets above that recreate the issue. Sorry about the lack of detail, I was on a tablet and didn't have access to all the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this](http://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/blob/master/src/helpers/functions/Get-EnvironmentVariableNames.ps1), [this](http://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/blob/master/src/helpers/functions/Get-EnvironmentVariable.ps1), and [this](http://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/blob/672244c0ba4060ef27ad8bedabdbddb755b85a50/src/helpers/functions/Update-SessionEnvironment.ps1), i made [upd_env.ps1](http://gist.github.com/swestner/b56b8d361b6974019556). Then I call the script after doing any installs :

```
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))    
cinst nodejs.install
cinst npm
.\upd_env.ps1
npm install -g bower
```

And all is good.